# How to add last command in zsh prompt?

Tags: shell, zsh, prompt

I do not want the command number or the exit status, I want the command to be displayed in my zsh prompt. Does anybody know if this is possible, and how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want more formatting, but:

```
  preexec() { PS1="$2\$ "; }
```